# React useReducer setup for large state

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer

I have a React application with a rather large state. I have been using useState since the beginning, but it has grown a lot and suddenly there are almost 100 useState lines.

Now I think it is time to switch to useReducer (I know - I should have done this cleanup way earlier).

The states are a mix of simple booleans, numbers, strings, objects and arrays of objects (and nested objects), eg.

```
const [type, setArea] = useState<Area>(getDefaultArea());
const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([]);
const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);
...
```

How do I best organize these? Should I create 1 giant useReducer with everything? Or group the variables into multiple smaller useReducers? Should an array of objects have its own useReducer?

I have not used useReducer before, but I have read a bunch of articles, but they all walk through simple counter samples and does not really descripe how to organize a large state.

I'm also planning to move part of these into a context, but one step at a time.

If anybody can point me in the right direction, I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: *I should have done this cleanup way earlier* - maybe, but don't start refactoring too fast. Are all of these states tightly coupled? Are they all needed in several components requiring prop drilling? If no to one or both of these questions, I would leave the code as-is. There's nothing wrong with having several (even a lot) of useStates. This separation was actually an original *advantage* of useState vs class state.

Comment: If your problem is prop-drilling, but the states aren't tightly coupled, I would recommend using redux. It operates very similar to useReducer, but will handle a lot of the boilerplate that you'd have to create yourself with useReducer.

Comment: If you insist on refactoring, you should find ways to understand which states are coupled and make reducers for those as a starting point. A good example would be fetching data, as there are usually multiple states involved in data retrieval, such as loading, error, and storing the data itself.